# Queries to count points lying on arbitrary line

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

Suppose we have N points on XY plane, ie. (x, y) and x and y are integers and there are multiple queries where each query is of the form y = mx + c and given m and c where m and c are integers.

Is it possible to count number of points that lie on the given line more efficiently than O(N) per query?

I believe some preprocessing might help or some data structure like QuadTree that counts points inside arbitrary rectangle.

The queries are offline so if it's possible using some batch processing technique or even SQRT optimization it would be better than naive brute force.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/160392/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76352746/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the points into subsets, and use different subsets for the different lines.

For example, one subset could be points where x is less than y. For lines where m>1 and c>0, x will always be less than y, so you could use this subset for those cases. Conversely, another subset could be the points where y is greater than x. This could be used for lines where m<1 and c<0.

If you have a large number of lines, or if the time taken to do this preprocessing is not important, then this might improve things significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider preprocessing a dual plane according to the following transformation:

```
point p => line p* as a*p_x - p_y
line l as ax + b => point l* as (a, -b)
```

Find all intersections of the lines in the dual plane using some known, efficient method.

Each query as a line input would equal a point in the dual plane. Each intersection in the dual plane represents points on the same line in the original plane.